# Anatomically Correct Sciapod

Tags: creature-design, fantasy-races, anatomy, humanoid, anatomically-correct

The sciapod is a small humanoid creature, which is distinguished by a single large leg. This leg would be like a single leg, without duplicate structures. It would also be symmetrical. They move by jumping around, and are quite quick. The leg would be roughly as flexible as a human leg

While sirenomelia and such things can cause the legs to fuse, this wouldn't work for the sciapods; because of their powerful leaps, they need a solid pelvis (or other such joint), which is not found with sirenomelia

**How would such a being fit together internally?**

[image: Picture]

Comment: What is the range of motion you envision for their single leg?

Comment: Pictures please

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sirenomelia

Comment: What is a "saltatorial"?

Comment: @Daron Adapted for Leaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Above the pelvis.

Locomotion with one leg is rather... interesting. Not only does the ball joint of the femur have to be at the centre of the pelvis but there also needs to be room for the muscles around it. This means that the urinary system and anal tract need to be placed ABOVE the pelvis and not under/inside of it.

To picture this, sciapods butts and genitals would sit just above their leg. A single buttcheek to boot! And the anus would be on top, how unfortunate... I imagine that if they wore clothes they would have little belts or tunics to hide their parts.

Advice for sciapods: don't pee while squatting.